# Reflecting on the class of the immediate ancestor

Tags: ruby, inheritance

```
Apple < ActiveRecord:Base
Orange < ActiveRecord:Base

piece_of_fruit = Apple.new
```

**I want to know whether `piece_of_fruit` is an `Apple` or an `Orange`** - *even though both are derived from `ActiveRecord:Base`*.

Is there a reflection method that will tell me the next class in the inheritance tree (Apple/Orange).

What about if I want to look at each successive step in the inheritance hierarchy after that, starting with ActiveRecord:Base in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_a` and `kind_of` are synonymous, so you can write either of the following:

```
piece_of_fruit.is_a?(Apple)
```

or

```
piece_of_fruit.kind_of?(Apple)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
piece_of_fruit.kind_of?(Apple)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question, as others have posted, is

```
piece_of_fruit.is_a? Apple
```

The answer to your second question ("What if I want to look at each successive step in the inheritance hierarchy?") is to use the `class` and `superclass` methods.

```
piece_of_fruit.class 
=> Apple
piece_of_fruit.class.superclass     
=> ActiveRecord::Base
```